# What should be the schema for the JSON in Big Query?

Tags: json, schema, google-bigquery

I have the following JSON and i have to import it to Big Query. What schema should i specify for the below JSON? What should be the field names of the table? I am using BigQuery WebUI.

```
     {
      "users": {
        "userid1mohan": {
          "password": "123456",
          "username": "mohan"
        },
        "userid2kutubuddin": {
          "password": "234567",
          "username": "kutubuddin"
        },
        "userid3pankaj": {
          "password": "345678",
          "username": "pankaj"
        },
        "userid4vivek": {
          "password": "456789",
          "username": "vivek"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that BigQuery will easily ingest CSVs and newline delimited JSONs, but not a plain JSON file like the one provided in the question.

Find a specification on the newline delimited JSON format here: http://dataprotocols.org/ndjson/

For a use case like this one, the nljson would need to look like:

```
{"username":"kutubuddin","password":"456789"}
{"username":"pankaj","password":"312231"}
{"username":"vivek","password":"123h1"}
```

So you'll need to transform the json object you have into multiple json objects, one in each line, before ingesting it into BigQuery.

Comment: in users i have some userid like userid1mohan, userid2kutubuddin etc. How can i create a schema for them?

Comment: why would you want to create a schema for them? think in terms of tables, and how things fit in columns

Comment: hmims may want nested schema. "user" could be a field of type RECORD which could contain fields "username" and "password". See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes. Note that formatting is as Felipe suggests, but it would be {"user":{"username":"kutubuddin","password":"456789"}} all on one line.

Comment: Thanks Felipe and Michael...I agree with Felipe..so now i would be adding this employeeid key in the table itself